# Chrome.storage appending values to an object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have the following block of code that's behaving unexpectedly:

```
//Where url and info are strings
function addURL(url, info){
    chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
        items[url] = info;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({"data" : items}, function() {});
    }); 
}
```

My goal is to take the "data" key value pair out of storage, add a new index to that object with the key of url and the value of minutes, and then replace the previous 'data' value with the new one.

Instead, I'm creating a nested structure where this code executes correctly the first time through, but on subsequent adds there become nested "data" blocks inside the object as follows:

```
data
  url3 -> info3
  data
    url2 -> info2
        data
        url1 -> info1
```

While what I would expect is

```
data
    url1 -> info1
    url2 -> info2
    url3 -> info3
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you log or inspect the contents of the parameter `items` passed to your callback function you'll find out it has the format: `{ data: {...} }`.
So you just need to do:

```
    items.data[url] = info;

    chrome.storage.sync.set(items, function() {});
```